# How to create a panel-wide button with an arrow in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm interested in creating a button in my project, like the "Remove" button here:

[image]

I've seen numerous posts here describing how it's done, but all are saying to enter a Unicode arrow as the button's text, which is completely unrelated to my end goal. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: A custom control with anchors left and right having a panel with inside: a label dock left for the arrow image and a label dock fill for the caption, with some code to the rendering? Or a already-made and standardized control...

Comment: @OlivierRogier I could, but I've also seen this kind of button in some Windows troubleshooting dialogs, all the way back to Windows Vista and 7. That's why I think that MS must have created a similar control to make things easier during the development of the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the web, I finally found that such a button was for **Task Dialogs** :

[About Task Dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/task-dialogs-overview)

[TaskDialog Class (WinForms)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.taskdialog)

[WPF TaskDialog Wrapper and Emulator](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137552/WPF-TaskDialog-Wrapper-and-Emulator)

[Krypton Toolkit task Dialogs](https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton)

There are a few questions on Stack Overflow but they are too specific on small issues without any general tutorials, and I did not find a duplicate.

Comment: I found it in the WPF TaskDialog wrapper, it was a CommandBox. Thank you for helping me out!